# upstart start splash process before any other process

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, splash-screen

I am customizing ubuntu running on an arm based  embedded system. Rather than use plymouth (splash) for hiding the startup messages, I am using a custom executable called psplash directly which writes to the framebuffer. Now I need to make sure that this splash process starts before any other process. This system has many unavoidable upstart jobs. However I try, I am always getting some messages from the upstart jobs before the splash takes over the screen.
This is my psplash job:

```
description "Userspace bootsplash utility"

start on runlevel [2345]

expect fork
kill timeout 60

script
#        exec /sbin/psplash
    sleep 2
end script

pre-start script
    echo "PSPLASH"
     /sbin/psplash
    sleep 2
end script
```

To make sure that it is started early, I  initiated the  process  in "pre-start" and to make sure that other jobs get started after a delay, I added  sleep in "script".

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21378/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-starts-before-other-upstart-jobs) post, I created another service which forces other jobs to start only after this psplash job. But thats also not optimal as I need add lot of system level jobs which gets stuck in this scenario.

```
    #service-psplash-wait.conf

    start on (starting alsa-restore
    or starting anacron
    or starting apport
    or starting atd
    or starting auto-serial-console
    or starting avahi-daemon
    or starting binfmt-support
    or starting bluetooth
    or starting console-setup
    or starting console
    or starting container-detect
    or starting control-alt-delete
    or starting cron
    or starting cups
    or starting dbus
    or starting dmesg

    )


# We know that we have more than one job that needs to wait for service-a and
# will make use of this service, so we need to instantiate.
instance $JOB

# Needed to make starting the job successful despite being killed
normal exit 2
task

script

status psplash | grep -q "start/running" && exit 0
start psplash || true

# Waiting forever is ok.. upstart will kill this job when
# the service-a we tried to start above either starts or stops
while sleep 3600 ; do :; done

end script
```

And even if psplash is the first process which is initiated, it might need some time to take over the display. So no other messages should be displayed during this time. Blank screen is OK.

What can I do?

Comment: What does the psplash job look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult :]

The following should start your job earlier in the boot. Does it suffice? (This is supposed to be without the wait job).

```
description "Userspace bootsplash utility"

start on virtual-filesystems

# adjust expect stanza as needed
exec /sbin/psplash
```